# Issues with Movie2Avi

Tags: matlab, movie

I'm trying to make a movie in the following way:

```
x=linspaces(1,10,100);

For i=1:100 
plot(x,sin(x))
M(i)=getframe;
end

movie2avi(M,'MOVIE01');
```

I get a response:

```
Warning: Cannot locate Indeo5 compressor, using 'None' as the compression type.
```

it makes the movie but I cannot open it ( gives an error)

I'm using windows 7 64 bit operation system and matlab 2012b

I've tryed the compression types in the documentation but recieved an error for all of them

Comment: You will find some possible compressors in the documentation for `movie2avi`, install one of these and use it.

Comment: [Indeo5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeo) is a codec from the 1990s that predates MPEG-1. Avoid it at all costs. Almost nothing supports it these days, the compression quality is terrible, and many implementations contain security vulnerabilities. As @nkjt says, the `VideoWriter` class is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> On some Windows systems, including all 64-bit systems, the default Indeo® 5 codec is not available. MATLAB issues a warning, and creates an uncompressed file.

It would be better to use [VideoWriter](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter-class.html), which I believe you should have in 2012b.